# Add folders in ubuntuone with kubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, kubuntu

I've installed the client for ubuntuone in my kubuntu 11.04 desktop but I'd like to add and sync some other folders of my home dir except the standard one, is it possible?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You will find almost everything you need here:

https://wiki.kubuntu.org/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/Files

Comment: But it's everything regarding Ubuntu, even if it's on the kubuntu section. I don't have the option "Ubuntu One" on the right click of the mouse.

Comment: I have just double checked launchpad and there is a developnment of a unbuntuone-client-kde (https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client-kde) It seems KDE was neglected to start with. You can upload individual files via the web interface but not whole folders.

I Apologise for that